# How to load a WAR module into Spring's built-in Tomcat running in a standalone?

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I am having three modules in my Maven project:

```
parent
  rest-api     #  Spring REST API
  web-client   #  AngularJS web client
  application  #  Project to bundle it all up for a standalone
```

I am not sure if I have here an "*elegant*" solution so please hit me with a stick if that is complete garbage, but this is how it works - or how it's supposed to work:

---

#### rest-api

Module `rest-api` does simply offer the REST API and other core functionality - basically it is pure server code. It is a `jar` artifact.

#### web-client

To separate client and server code I am having the module `web-client`. It is a `war` project that hold the client webapp.

#### application

This module is supposed to glue it all up. It depends on `rest-api` and `web-client`. It does two important things:

1. It's pom.xml uses the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` to build a standalone runnable `jar` - my ultimate goal
2. It provides the `main(String args[])` method that starts the `@SpringBootApplication` with `SpringApplication.run(EasyModelAccessServer.class, args);`

---

What I am currently able to is tell Eclipse to run this in a servlet container. The server boots up and I my two resources, the **rest-api** and the **web-client** working. Everything is fine so far.

### The issue

What is not fully working is the standalone. If I package up the whole thing and run the server:

```
$ path/to/application: mvn clean package
$ path/to/application: java -jar target/application.jar
```

Only the REST API will work. The reason is because the **web-client** is *not* added or introduced as a web app to the Spring built-in Tomcat.

### The question

is how I can make this work. There are two options which come to my mind:

1. Somehow sneak in the `web-client.war` file into the `application.jar` such that it is available as a resource and programmatically call `tomcat.addWebapp("/web-client", "path/to/web-client.war")` (or something like that) to load the additional service
2. Hope that the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` or another Spring Maven plug-in can do that for me and find somebody that links me to an example.

I've tried it with 1. but I didn't succeed to move `web-client.war` into `application.jar` but I am also not sure if I should actually do that.

---

#### FAQ

**Q:** "*Why do you separate everything instead of merge all those modules into a `server` module where the Spring Maven plug-in would do everything for you out of the box?*"

**A:** I really want to separate the client code from the server code. I *could* however merge `web-client` into `application` but last time I tried that I had 10 other issues why this did not work out so I decided to keep it that way and that it actually shouldn't be so hard to load an additional server resource.

**Q:** "*Can I take a look at the project?*"

**A:** Yes, you can. Just take a look: https://github.com/silentsnooc/easy-model-access Please forgive me that I am currently using tabs instead of whitespaces - I am going to change that as soon as I got everything up and running.

Comment: I would not create a specific "application" module, your "web-client" looks like the ideal candidate for being SpringBootified. Making it Bootiful will do the same as the "servlet container" run by Eclipse

Comment: @Tome That would mean I remove `application` and move the `@SpringBootAnnotation` class into `web-client`, right? Last time I tried that I had several issues that made me give up this approach. At first I couldn't simply start the application in Eclipse anymore with the Tomcat plug-in. Then I also wasn't able to build the standalone with the Spring Maven plugin and so on. I am sure that this can be done somehow but I don't know how exactly. Is it really such a stupid idea to separate the code the way I do it?

Comment: If the web-client is pure JS, that can indeed cause issues if you want to keep it separated. My first guess was that rest-api was pure Java API and web-client contained Java implementation and JS front-end. Split like you did, "application" module would have to depend on "web-client" JS resources (with an assembly there?) rather than a WAR.

Comment: @Tome No, `rest-api` is using the Spring Framework to handle REST calls. Yes, `web-client` is pure JS. Imho a client should not have anything to do with its server - especially if it's not even written in the same language but I guess that's what causing my headache at the moment. But yes, `application` would have to depend on `web-client` in some way. An option is to load this WAR manually like I did it [here](https://github.com/silentsnooc/easy-model-access/blob/master/ema-server/server/src/main/java/org/ema/server/Server.java#L46) or the Spring Maven plugin offers an easier way.

Comment: @Tome The last option of course would be to take `rest-api` and `web-client` and merge them back together into just one single project that contains the server code for the REST API and all other layers + the code for the actual web application.